# Web3js 1.0.0-beta.35 sendSignedTransaction() Error

Tags: web3js, infura

I am using ropsten.infura as my provider. It is my very first time to use infura so please bear with me.

This is my code for requesting the transaction.

```
web3().eth.getTransactionCount(coinbase)
    .then(nonce => {
            console.log(nonce)
            const privateKey = new Buffer(pKey, 'hex')
            let data = newContractInstance.methods.redeem('0x91320aBaa4eA71BcDaE54f99eD6a6D36D44539C7', 5).encodeABI()
            let rawTx = {
                nonce: nonce,
                gasPrice: 10000000000,
                gasLimit: 3000000,
                data: data
            }

            let Tx = new ETHtx(rawTx)
            Tx.sign(privateKey)
            let serializedTx = '0x' + Tx.serialize().toString('hex')

            web3().eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx)
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)
                resolve(result)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
                reject(error)
            })
```

I believe that it is successfully contacting the contract but the transaction is being reverted with this error below.

```
index.js:2178 Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
```

`{
  "blockHash": "0x50af6435e625d8f52043c376ebd7d890651f64fcc847089a781bb700967ea048",
  "blockNumber": 4063823,
  "contractAddress": "0x253cE628Df83F20AFAD04C86852D154707e1BF62",
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 5180761,
  "from": "0x91320abaa4ea71bcdae54f99ed6a6d36d44539c7",
  "gasUsed": 3000000,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": null,
  "transactionHash": "0xc52822264a278afdc521b3759d9b4fbb56e4c18d5c52ccb62f90d0741e4dcfc7",
  "transactionIndex": 38
}`

I am not so sure why the transaction is being reverted. I believe it has nothing to do with the modifiers as I have successfully used the same method using metamask before. One thing I noticed about using the sendSignedTransaction() is the contractAddress property. The given contractAddress is not the contractAddress that I was trying to contact and the value also changes on each transaction. Is it really how it behaves and does it represent the contractAddress that you are going to access? I hope someone can enlighten me with this.

### Contract Code

```
    function redeem(address _user, uint256 _amount)
    public
    hasStarted
    onlyOwner
    returns (bool)
{
    uint256 _balanceOf = balanceOf[_user];
    if (totalRemainingToken < _amount) return false;
    if (_balanceOf + _amount < _balanceOf) return false;
    totalRemainingToken -= _amount;
    balanceOf[_user] += _amount;
    emit Redeem(msg.sender, _user, _amount);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code of the smart contract you are calling?

Comment: @Henk I have edited the question and included the method code.

Comment: "One thing I noticed about using the sendSignedTransaction() is the contractAddress property." Are you sure you are using the address of the contract you deployed to the Ropsten testnet to instantiate `newContractInstance` in your JS code?

Comment: `I believe it has nothing to do with the modifiers` - why don't you get rid of the modifiers and give it another go, just to verify this assumption of yours?

Comment: @Henk Yes. I've used the balanceOf method of the contract using newContractInstance and was able to get the correct value.

Comment: Also, for best practice, I would replace `let serializedTx = '0x' + Tx.serialize().toString('hex')` with `let temp = Tx.serialize().toString('hex')` followed by `let serializedTx = '0x' + '0'.repeat(40 - temp.length) + temp`.

Comment: @goodvibration I've tried it and still got the same error result.

Comment: @goodvibration I'm sorry for this question but why is this `let serializedTx = '0x' + '0'.repeat(40 - temp.length) + temp` a best way?

Comment: Make sure that the address is 40 character long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transaction is missing the "to" field.

```
{
  ...
  "status": false,
  "to": null,         <--------
  ..
}
```

Ethereum will interpret that transaction as a contract creation using your "data" as the contract bytecode, and it fails because it is not valid.

For it to work you have to set "to" to your contract address, in web3 v1.0 to obtain the contract address you can use [newContractInstance.options.address](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#options-address)

```
let rawTx = {
    to: newContractInstance.options.address,
    nonce: nonce,
    gasPrice: 10000000000,
    gasLimit: 3000000,
    data: data
}
```

Comment: this made it work. Thank you very much for the answer. I misinterpreted the _'(optional) The destination address of the message'_ of the **'to'** property for raw transactions, I thought it is only use when you are sending eth to another address.